# Ascii arrays in hangman is not updating

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have created a hangman game in python 3. The game is working fine. The letters are working fine. Everything is working fine. There is one thing that is bothering me. After I type the wrong word, the ascii drawing is not updating. It is still on the first drawing though the life gets reduced. It is made for five chances and after five attempts player gets killed. The drawing is not updating.
I am doing lessons from invent with python.

```
import random
HANGMANPICS = ['''

  +---+
  |   |
      |
      |
      |
      |
=========''', '''

  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
      |
      |
      |
=========''', '''

  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
  |   |
      |
      |
=========''', '''

  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|   |
      |
      |
=========''', '''

  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|\  |
      |
      |
=========''', '''

  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|\  |
 /    |
      |
=========''', '''

  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|\  |
 / \  |
      |
=========''']
words = 'ant baboon badger bat bear beaver camel cat clam cobra cougar coyote crow deer dog donkey duck eagle ferret fox frog goat goose hawk lion lizard llama mole monkey moose mouse mule newt otter owl panda parrot pigeon python rabbit ram rat raven rhino salmon seal shark sheep skunk sloth snake spider stork swan tiger toad trout turkey turtle weasel whale wolf wombat zebra'.split()

def getRandomWord(wordList):

    wordIndex = random.randint(0, len(wordList) - 1)
    return wordList[wordIndex]

def displayBoard(HANGMANPICS, missedLetters, correctLetters, secretWord):
    print(HANGMANPICS[len(missedLetters)])
    print()

    print('Missed letters:', end =' ')
    for letter in missedLetters:
        print(letter, end=' ')
    print()

    blanks = '_' * len(secretWord)

    for i in range(len(secretWord)):
        if secretWord[i] in correctLetters:
            blanks = blanks[:i] + secretWord[i] + blanks[i+1:]

    for letter in blanks:
        print(letter, end=' ')
    print()

def getGuess(alreadyGuessed):
    while True:
        print('Guess a letter.')
        guess = input()
        guess = guess.lower()
        if len(guess) != 1:
            print('Please enter a single letter')
        elif guess in alreadyGuessed:
            print('You have already guessed this letter.Choose again')
        elif guess not in 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz':
            print('Please enter a letter.')
        else:
            return guess


def playAgain():

    print('Want to play again, yes or no?')
    return input().lower().startswith('y')


print('H A N G M A N')
missedLetters = ''
correctLetters = ''
secretWord = getRandomWord(words)
gameIsDone = False

while True:
    displayBoard(HANGMANPICS, missedLetters, correctLetters, secretWord)

    #let the player type the letter
    guess = getGuess(missedLetters + correctLetters)

    if guess in secretWord:
        correctLetters = correctLetters + guess

        foundAllLetters = True
        for i in range(len(secretWord)):
            if secretWord[i] not in correctLetters:
                foundAllletters = False
                break
            if foundAllLetters:
                print('Yes the secret word is' + secretWord + 'You have won')
                gameIsDone = True
    else:
        missedletters = missedLetters + guess

        #check players has guessed to many times and lost
        if len(missedLetters) == len(HANGMANPICS) - 1:
            displayBoard(HANGMANPICS, missedLetters, correctLetters, secretWord)
            print('You have run out of guesses! \nAfter ' + str(len(missedLetters)) + ' missed guesses and ' + str(len(correctLetters)) + ' correct guesses , the word was ' + secretword + '!')
            gameIsDone = True


    #Ask the player if they want to play again
    if gameIsDone:
        if playAgain():
            missedLetters = ''
            correctLetters = ''
            gameIsDone = False
            secretWord = getRandomWord(words)
        else:
            break
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your capitalization of your variables:

```
# You have
missedletters = missedLetters + guess
# should be
missedLetters = missedLetters + guess
      ^
```

Also:

```
# You have
... + ' correct guesses , the word was ' + secretword + '!')
# should be
... + ' correct guesses , the word was ' + secretWord + '!')
                                                 ^
```

The first issue was causing your board not to update -- the second one caused it not run (for me).